# Solving time-dependent two-levels hamiltonian

Tags: schroedinger-equation, hamiltonian, time-evolution, two-level-system, rabi-model

I would like to solve the time-dependent Schrodinger equation for a two-levels system with a time-dependent Hamiltonian ($ \hbar = 1 $)

$$ H(t) = \frac{\Omega_R}{2} i (\sigma_+ e^{i t \Delta}-\sigma_- e^{-i t \Delta}) , $$

where $ \Omega_R $ and $ \Delta$ are constants,

$$ \sigma_+ := \left[\matrix{0&0\cr 1&0}\right] $$ and $$ \sigma_- := \left[\matrix{0&1\cr 0&0}\right]. $$

I know that a brutal force method would be to solve the differential equation with the time ordered exponential, but I am looking for others possible methods.

Thank you all!

Comment: One could try Floquet theory, too, which yields a systematic way of solving periodic time-dependent systems.

Answer (score 1):

You may try to perform a (time-dependent) unitary transform to remove the time-dependence of your Hamiltonian. Remember that if
$$|\psi'\rangle=U|\psi\rangle$$
then
$$H'=UHU^{-1}+i\hbar{dU\over dt}U^{-1}$$
for $|\psi'\rangle$ to satisfy Schrödinger equation with the Hamiltonian $H'$. I would suggest to try the transformation (without guaranty)
$$U=e^{i\Delta\sigma^z t}$$
You should end up with a $2\times 2$ time-independent Hamiltonian that you can diagonalize. Finally, it remains to apply the inverse transformation $U^{-1}$ to the eigenvectors.